# Can two different App with the same name exist in App Store?

Tags: ios-appstore

Is it possible I use same name but different icon for an App I sumbit to App Store?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, the name of your app as it appears in the App Store must be unique.  When creating your app, you will receive the following error if you try to use a name that is already taken:

> The Application Name that you provided has already been used. Please provide a unique Application Name.

But the name on the icon can be whatever you want - it can be the same as another app's icon name.

Source: [Quora](http://www.quora.com/Can-two-iPhone-apps-have-the-same-name)